# Android WebView : is (de)compression supported?

Tags: android, webview, compression

I'm trying to optimise delivery of a web page of mine that can either be viewed in a desktop browser, or within an app of mine via a `WebView`.

I've tried enabling gzip compression at the web server, and it works fine when viewing the content on the desktop, and even in Chrome on my Android device.  But in a `WebView`, it isn't showing.

So is the `WebView` just too basic?  I'm talking Android 4.1 here.

Thanks.

Comment: I would like to know this as well. Did you ever get an answer?

Comment: Hmm, it's so long ago now I really can't remember :-(  I'll try to have a look.  I know that compression is still enabled at the web server, and it's showing fine in the `WebView`, but I'm not sure what (if anything) I did.  I'll try to remember.